# add field to bundle through hook_entity_bundle_field_info

Tags: 8, entities

I am trying to add two fields to one of the node bundles.

I define the fields in this function:

```
function concertbeheer_entity_bundle_field_info(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle, array $base_field_definitions){
    if($entity_type->id()=="node" && $bundle == "concert")
    {
        $concert_fields['laatste_uitvoering'] = \Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
                ->setLabel('Laatste uitvoering')
                ->setRequired(TRUE)
                ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
                ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', FALSE)
                ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
                    'label'=>'inline',
                    'type' => 'datetime_plain',
                    'weight' => '999',
                ));
        $concert_fields['eerste_uitvoering'] = \Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
                ->setLabel('Eerste uitvoering')
                ->setRequired(TRUE)
                ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
                ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', FALSE)
                ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
                    'label'=>'inline',
                    'type' => 'datetime_plain',
                    'weight' => '999',
                ));

        return $concert_fields;

    }


}
```

but the documentation on https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_bundle_field_info/8.2.x says I also need to provide a fieldStorageDefinition through hook_entity_field_storage_info()

I can actually configure the visibility of the fields but when I save something to them it isn't saved in DB. Probably because of the lack of a FieldStorageDefinition

But I don't know how to get started on that and, as usual, there seems to be no documentation available on how to do it

Answer (score 3):

This code example would set up a basic storage definition:

```
function mymodule_entity_field_storage_info(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() == 'node') {
    $definitions['my_bundle_field'] = \Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setName('my_bundle_field')
      ->setLabel(t('My new bundle field'))
      ->setTargetEntityTypeId($entity_type->id());
    return $definitions;
  }
}
```

You can look up examples in `field.storage.*.yml` files from a config export.

If you don't find the right examples there, you can configure a field in UI and then export the storage of this field to get a blueprint for the storage definition you need in this hook.

Comment: Very odd but I get an error that the class Drupal\entity_test\FieldStorageDefinition cannot be found. Seems like a bug in D8 if you ask me...

Comment: Yes, this seems to be an issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2280639. You can try to use BaseFieldDefinition, see the edited answer.

Comment: Why don't you install the bundle fields with yaml files?

Comment: Because probably he/she works on a module and not possible to upgrade a bundle with yaml? You are just allowed to install field when the module installed (or the field dependencies) but there's no way to do it without re-installation of the module, which is not acceptable.

Comment: @golddragon007, this is about whether to install the field storage of a bundle field with a hook or a yaml file. The hook solution had some issues and is not used very often. That's the question about, why just don't use a yaml file. What you are refering to is a different topic, how to add fields to existing bundles after you have a storage. For this you need to modify the config entries of the existing bundle, view mode and form mode.

Comment: @4k4, well, he/she says: "I am trying to add two fields to one of the node bundles." so there's an existing bundle, and he/she want to add new field. (exactly 2). There's no information about he/she has previously added field or fields in yml, but a reason why he/she doesn't use or want to use yml, because of an example which I wrote. If you want to modify the config entries, unfortunately it's not enough to update config entities with `configFactory` because it won't shows up the field for some reason if you do it throw `hook_update`.

Comment: @golddragon007, the question is about `hook_entity_bundle_field_info`. See title, code example and linked reference.